# How to SELECT the 10 highest values ​from a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a leaderboard that will only show a top 10 people with the highest `level` and `xp`, this means that I not only need to evaluate the `level` for the 10 highest values, but also that it is known that the `xp` exists to know who is the one who must be above the other.

my table currently:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_level(
user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
level INT UNSIGNED,
xp BIGINT UNSIGNED,
req BIGINT UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id))
```

Comment: Your table has no name

Comment: yes i forgot to add it but i fixed it.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Do a two level sort, first by `level`, then by `xp`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY level DESC, xp DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks! If I need to see only the range, how can I do it? Knowing that I only want a number to return, Example there are 5 users with different levels and xp `(1, 20), (2, 0), (3, 29), (7, 62), (10, 79)` and I would be the sixth user, it should return `2` if the value is `(8, 0)` level 8, xp 0. I want to remember that he will not only be 15 it could be 10,000.

Comment: I don't understand what you want in your comment above, but, in any case, it sounds like you should probably open a new question, as the one you already asked above has been answered.

Comment: Well, Thanks anyway.